# datepicker trigger event in yii

Tags: yii, datepicker

My view code goes like this

```
<div class="row col2">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'visited_date'); ?>
    <?php 

    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute'=>'visited_date',
        'options'=>array(
            'showAnim'=>'drop',//'slide','fold','slideDown','fadeIn','blind','bounce','clip','drop'
            'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
            'showButtonPanel' => true,      
        ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array('size'=>30,'class'=>'date',  //'value'=> date("Y-m-d")

         ),
    ));
  ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'visited_date'); ?>
</div>

    <div class="row col2">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'next_visited_date'); ?>
    <?php 
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute'=>'next_visited_date',
        'options'=>array(
            'showAnim'=>'drop',`enter code here`
            'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
            'showButtonPanel' => true,
            ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
    'style'=>'height:20px; border-color: #448844;color:red; float:left;',
),
    ));
  ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'next_visited_date'); ?>
</div>
```

I am using yii 1 framework. I have two date pickers in my form i.e one to select visited-Date and another to select next-visitedDate. My next-visitedDate changes according to visited-Date i  select .How to do so?

How to trigger on one date select to another datepicker? Please anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `onSelect` event for your first dropdown:

```
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute'=>'visited_date',
        'options'=>array(
            'showAnim'=>'drop',//'slide','fold','slideDown','fadeIn','blind','bounce','clip','drop'
            'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
            'showButtonPanel' => true,
            'onSelect'=> 'js:function( visitedDate ) {
                  $("#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'next_visited_date').'").datepicker( "option", "minDate", visitedDate );// or some other logic
             }',      
        ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array('size'=>30,'class'=>'date',  //'value'=> date("Y-m-d")

         ),
    ));
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a complete rough example:

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
    'name'=>'start-date',
    'options'=>array(        
        'showButtonPanel'=>true,
        'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
        'onSelect'=> 'js:function( visitedDate ) {
                  date      = new Date(visitedDate);
                  date.setMonth( date.getMonth( ) + 1 );
                  newDate = date.getFullYear( )+"-"+( date.getMonth( ) + 1 )+"-"+date.getDate( );
                  console.log(newDate);
                  $("#end_date").val(newDate);
             }',
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
    ),
));
?>

<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
    'name'=>'end-date',
    'options'=>array(        
        'showButtonPanel'=>true,
        'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
      'id'=>"end_date"
    ),
));
?>
```

Comment: when i select vistedDate i have to make calculations to display date in next-visitedDate.how to do that?

Comment: @ManiRatna okay, then do those calculations inside `onSelect` function ?

Comment: I have no idea doing that.suppose i have to add 30 days in the seleted date to display in next visited date. how can it be done?

Comment: @ManiRatna I have added a rough example, check my updated answer.

Comment: thank you it was helpful for me. if i want to pass any value in onSelect function lets say drop down box value .is it possible to do that?

Comment: @ManiRatna Yes It Is :). Its plain jquery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95306/discussion-between-criesto-and-mani-ratna).